# Unable to run app on IOS simulator after creating multiple schemes in Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, ios-simulator

I'm implementing flavors in Flutter in order to have separate build settings for the development and staging server. After following [this article](https://medium.com/@animeshjain/build-flavors-in-flutter-android-and-ios-with-different-firebase-projects-per-flavor-27c5c5dac10b), I have added multiple schemes, but now I'm unable to run it on an ios simulator (Haven't tested it on a real device yet).

I get the following error

```
Error (Xcode): Target aot_assembly_release failed: Exception: release/profile
builds are only supported for physical devices. attempted to build for
simulator.
```

Here's y configuration for schemes,

### Development

[image]

### Staging

[image]

### Runner Info

[image]

Comment: Same here, did you find the solution yet?

Comment: I tried it again, but this time I didn't change the base `scheme` `Runner` or base `build config` `Debug, Release, Profile` and just added the new ones separately, and it worked. See this tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Y7WaeU3P60&t=741s